# libcurl and mkdir

Tags: c, libcurl

I need to use libcurl for creating a folder in my home directory. I use the following set of code for this:

```
struct curl_slist *headers = NULL; 
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "mkdir MyFolder"); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_QUOTE, headers);
```

I have given the ftp server-path, user name, password. But, I get the error '500 COmmand not understood'.

I tried using 'pwd' command instead of 'mkdir MyFolder'. It worked without any error.

Can some one help me out to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use MKD instead of mkdir.

See [FILE TRANSFER PROTOCOL (FTP) RFC0959](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/rfc0959.txt).

Comment: @Judge Maygarden Thanks for adding the link and covering up my laziness ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since MKD (MKDIR) is an optional command in the FTP protocol, maybe the FTP server is configured not to allow it?  Can you do the MKD on the target server when you connect manually?